# CSS Positioning not working on IE 11 neither Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, flexbox

The problem I'm facing is some elements are not being positioned correctly in both Firefox and IE, It is working properly in Chrome.
Here is how it looks like:

[image]

### The correct way is like Chrome shows it.

[Fiddle here.](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/egMNZP?editors=1100)

```css
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-item-x4 {
  width: 25%;
}

.hr-menu-item-fix {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: large;

  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.hr-menu-item-fix:hover {
  height: 130%;
  width: 30%;

  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.hdr-fix {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 600px;

  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in 0;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in 0;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in 0;
}

.link-btn-menu-fixed {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-btn-menu-fixed {
  display: none;
}

.text-btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

#text-user {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="hdr-fix">
  <span class="column column-item-x4 hr-menu-item-fix" style="background-color: dimgray;">
              <a href="#" class="link-btn-menu-fixed" style="color: white;">
                <div class="icon-btn-menu-fixed"><i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="text-btn" id="text-user"><b>Item 1</b></div>
              </a>
            </span>
  <span class="column column-item-x4 hr-menu-item-fix" style="background-color: dimgray;">
              <a href="#" class="link-btn-menu-fixed" style="color: white;">
                <div class="icon-btn-menu-fixed" id="icon-folder"><i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="text-btn" id="text-folder"><b>Item 2</b></div>
              </a>
            </span>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what is happening, but I'm sure I'm misunderstanding some concepts regarding to positioning. Any suggestion and improvements are very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the below from: .text-btn

```
top:100%;
```

This will resolve the problem, however I personally wouldn't have created these boxes using positions, creating boxes using padding seems a lot more reliable to me also.
You already have used the     justify-content:center; to do center these vertically so really there is no reason for the top:100%; that I can see.

Hope this makes sense and hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: My fault, I've omitted some information. I'm used scroll-then-fix in my header, and it has and `:hover` event to show icon/text. That's why I'm using that `top: 100%;`. In Chrome, it was a way to avoid creating two clases, one for fixed header and another one for scrolling header. The problem came up because (apparently) IE and Firebox override parent's props.

Comment: So while I find a reason, I'm going to remove that `top: 100%;`. But I'd like to understand why It is happening.